# flyway error due to 'FROM' text inside an Insert statement using a SELECT

Tags: flyway

Using Flyway 3.2.1. Calling from command line in windows.

This line seems to be causing an error due to a parsing issue by flyway. Will a fix be available in a future release?

Statement That fails:
INSERT INTO CODE_TYPE_DISPLAY_TEMP (OBJECT_ID, LANG_CD, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USER_CD, DISPLAY_TXT) (SELECT CD_TYP_ID,'AMERICAN',SYSDATE,'CONVERSION','From Term Period Type' FROM CODE_TYPE WHERE CD_GRP_CD = 'DDE_FIELD_NME_TYP' AND CD_TYP_CD='FROM_TERM_PERIOD_DT_TYP');

SOLUTION:
Added || in the 2 words FROM and now it works.

INSERT INTO CODE_TYPE_DISPLAY_TEMP (OBJECT_ID, LANG_CD, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USER_CD, DISPLAY_TXT) (SELECT CD_TYP_ID,'AMERICAN',SYSDATE,'CONVERSION','Fr' || 'om Term Period Type' FROM CODE_TYPE WHERE CD_GRP_CD = 'DDE_FIELD_NME_TYP' AND CD_TYP_CD='FR' || 'OM_TERM_PERIOD_DT_TYP');

Another example of insert that fails.

```
--##################################################################################
--## Table(s) UPDATED: LABEL and
--##                   LABEL_DISPLAY
--##
--##
--## NOTE: The user can now modify the Display_txt. 
--##       Rule: In Label_Display> If DT != ODT then the user has modifed.
--##
--##       {-13} in txt is converted to a CR
--##       {-10} in txt is converted to a LF
--##
--##################################################################################
--SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED;

begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SCRIPT' || '_FYI:> ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') || '>===========================');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SCRIPT' || '_FYI:> ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') || '>= PROCESS LABELS   <STARTS>');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SCRIPT' || '_FYI:> ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') || '>===========================');
end;
/



-------------------------------------------------------
-- STEP 2
-- Create the table to hold the raw data from .dat files
-------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE DB_GIT_LABEL
(                                                         -- < TGT TBL MAPPINGS >                
LABEL_ID                    VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),            -- Label_ID                           
LABEL_KEY                   VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),           -- Label_Key                         
MAX_SHORT_LENGTH_NBR        VARCHAR2(3 CHAR),             -- Max_Short_Length_Nbr                            
DISPLAY_TXT                 VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)           -- [LABEL_DISPLAY] Display_Txt, Short_Display_Txt, Orig_Display_Txt                    
);


--######################################################################################
--# STEP 3
--# Inserts go here
--# SAMPLE: INSERT INTO DB_GIT_LABEL VALUES('LABEL_ID','LABEL_KEY','30','DISPLAY_TXT');
--######################################################################################

INSERT INTO DB_GIT_LABEL VALUES('0000','0518.fr' || 'om','30','Fr' || 'om');
INSERT INTO DB_GIT_LABEL VALUES('0001','0518.from','30','From');



--######################################################################################
--######################################################################################
COMMIT;
--######################################################################################
--######################################################################################


----------------------------------
-- DROP THE TEMP TABLE(S)
----------------------------------
DROP TABLE DB_GIT_LABEL cascade constraints purge;




begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SCRIPT' || '_FYI:> ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') || '>===========================');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SCRIPT' || '_FYI:> ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') || '>= PROCESS LABELS     <ENDS>');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SCRIPT' || '_FYI:> ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') || '>===========================');
end;
/
```

Comment: Here is a another example. Does anyone know why it's happening?

Comment: It looks like the problem occurs with the following words. THEN, USING and FROM

Comment: Can you share the error you getting without pipe (||), i think its not flyway issue.